# extra padding while taking screenshot using MediaProjection API

Tags: java, android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection

I am using the following code to obtain a screenshot. I get the screenshot but there is black padding attached to the image. The code samples found on the internet to take screenshot and to remove padding are used here:

```
// requesting permission
        MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(
            Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    startActivityForResult(projectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_SCREENSHOT);


// requesting screenshot on successful permission (in onActivityResult)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SCREENSHOT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        final MediaProjection mProjection = projectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);


        Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();
        mDisplay.getSize(size);

        final int width = size.x;
        final int height = size.y;


        final ImageReader mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mProjection.createVirtualDisplay("screen-mirror", width, height,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY |
                        DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC, mImageReader.getSurface(),
                null, null);


        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {

                final Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();

                if (image != null) {
                    mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                    mProjection.stop();

                    final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    final ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;

                    // create bitmap
                    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                    image.close();

                    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
            }
        }, null);


    }
```

Here is a screenshot showing what I am getting. I am loading the bitmap into an ImageView within my Activity.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the size that you got is incorrect.
You should change to:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
```

Then you should create another bitmap base on the bitmap you get from buffer

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
bmp.recycle();
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
iv.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but can I do this using one bitmap? Performance is critical to my app's usage and I have noticed that creating two bitmaps take additional time.

Comment: There is no way using one bitmap, I think. If you want to set the bitmap to ImageView, you can set the ImageView ration (width:height) is mWidth/mHeight, the set the scaleType to fitStart